# Using a toString method to print out adjusted variables

Tags: java, tostring

I have a very basic class here that I'm trying to use my first toString() method on.

```
 public class Shoes
{
   private String style;
   private String color;
   private double size;

   public Shoes()
   {
      this.style = " ";
      this.color = " ";
      this.size = 0;


   }

   public Shoes(String newStyle, String newColor, double newSize)
   {
      this.style = newStyle;
      this.color = newColor;
      this.size = newSize;

      System.out.println(this);

   }

   public String getStyle()
   {
      return style;
   }

   public void setStyle(String newStyle)
   {
      style = newStyle;
   }

   public String getColor()
   {
      return color;
   }

   public void setColor(String newColor)
   {

      color = newColor;
   }

   public double getSize()
   {
      return size;
   }

   public void setSize(double newSize)
   {
      size = newSize;
   }



   public String toString()
   {
      String myEol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
      return new String("Style: " + style + myEol + "Color: " + color + myEol + "Size: " + size);



   }


}
```

I'm trying to have it so that in my main class it will print out the variables data as it changes. Right now I only know how to call it inside of an overloaded constructor, but how would I print it AFTER the data has been changed from its initialized value?

Example of the main class, as you can see I'm using a default and overloaded.

```
public class ShoeStore
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


      Shoes nerdShoes = new Shoes();
      Shoes coolShoes = new Shoes("Sandals", "Brown", 8.5);

      nerdShoes.setColor("Tan");
      nerdShoes.setStyle("Walking");
      nerdShoes.setSize(9.5);

      System.out.println("The style of nerdShoes: " + nerdShoes.getStyle());

      coolShoes.setColor("Purple");

      System.out.println("The style of coolShoes: " + coolShoes.getStyle());



   }
}
```

**What I've done to Fix It**

```
public String toString()
   {
      String myEol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
      return new String("Style: " + getStyle() + myEol + "Color: " + getColor() + myEol + "Size: " + getSize());


   }
```

Instead of calling the variable itself I just called the function! I don't know how I missed that. Now it's printing properly!

Comment: Do you mean that as the data changes, itself, the `toString` method will be called? If so, you might want to check out tthe Oracle tutorial on writing a [property change listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)

Comment: Unclear what your desired effect should be. WHat do you want output to be?

Comment: If I understand right. You can just call your toString method:      `System.out.println(coolShoes.toString())`

Comment: So I'd like to have my program print out the style, color, and size of each object. I know I have two extra Sytstem.out.println(), but I'm trying to use the toString method to do it. My issue is that the toString method only prints the arguments from my overloaded constructor when I need it to print out what was changed, and not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add

```
System.out.println(this);
```

in each `set` method. For example:

```
public void setStyle(String newStyle)
{
   style = newStyle;
   System.out.println(this);
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I end up printing out the statement several times. It does eventually give me the correct result though.

Answer (score 0):

once you change the variable with one of your set methods it should automatically assign that to one of your member variables(fields). when you print out the object your toString() method should automatically be called since it overrides the default toString().

```
System.out.println(nerdShoes);
```

this will print out

```
//toString() method
("Style: " + getStyle() + myEol + "Color: " + getColor() + myEol + "Size: " + getSize());
```